# Using AutoMapper in the Edit action method in an MVC3 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

Here is my controller code, which works 100% as I need it to. However the POST method isn't using the AutoMapper and that is not OK. How can I use AutoMapper in this action method?

I'm using Entity Framework 4 with the Repository Pattern to access data.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Product product = _productRepository.FindProduct(id);
    var model = Mapper.Map<Product, ProductModel>(product);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ProductModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Product product = _productRepository.FindProduct(model.ProductId);

        product.Name = model.Name;
        product.Description = model.Description;
        product.UnitPrice = model.UnitPrice;

        _productRepository.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

If I use AutoMapper, the entity framework reference is lost and the data doesn't persist to the database.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ProductModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Product product = _productRepository.FindProduct(model.ProductId);
        product = Mapper.Map<ProductModel, Product>(model);

        _productRepository.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

I'm guessing this is caused the Mapper.Map function returning a brand new Product object and because of that, no references to the entity framework graph is being kept. What alternatives do you suggest?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem you are experiencing is. You say that your POST method is not using Automapper, but I don't see any Automapper code in your `[HttpPost]` method.

Comment: you're probably not posting back the right thing?

Comment: Not sure he means automapper Robert,  think he means "modelbinder"  but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: I edited in more details that should make the problem clearer. I don't mean ModelBinder, I mean the actual lib called AutoMapper.

Comment: oh, you want the map to map to an EXISTING object... what you are doing is turning a ProductModel into a new Product object.

Comment: @KeithNicholas: Yep, I know that's the problem. Can you suggest alternatives? I don't *want* to create a new Product object, but the Mapper.Map() method does this. Unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you just do

```
 Product product = _productRepository.FindProduct(model.ProductId);
 Mapper.Map(model, product);
 _productRepository.SaveChanges();
```

you may also want to check that you have a non null product first, and also that user is allowed to change that product....

Comment: Its correct , Actually we have to **create Map for Get and Post of Edit Method** , for Get Its: Domain Model To ViewModel Mappings and for Post Its: ViewModel To Domain Model Mappings , check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26908339/2218697), hope helps someone.