# MVC4 and AutoMapper 4.2.1: Property Can not be mapped error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I am having a problem getting my data written to my database. I get all the data loaded in to a View Model just fine, but then when I go to dump the data from the view model to the db model using AutoMapper I get

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>   Mapping types:
>   AttendanceTrackingEntry -> AttendanceTracking
>   eventTracking.Models.ViewModels.AttendanceTrackingEntry -> eventTracking.Models.AttendanceTracking
>   Destination path:
>   AttendanceTracking
>   Source value:
>   eventTracking.Models.ViewModels.AttendanceTrackingEntry
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>   Mapping types:
>   AttendanceTrackingEntry -> AttendanceTracking
>   eventTracking.Models.ViewModels.AttendanceTrackingEntry -> eventTracking.Models.AttendanceTracking
>   Destination path:
>   AttendanceTracking
>   Source value:
>   eventTracking.Models.ViewModels.AttendanceTrackingEntry

Here is what I have done:

**Database Model:**

```
public partial class AttendanceTracking
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public AttendanceTracking()
    {
        this.AttendanceItems = new HashSet<AttendanceItem>();
    }

    public long memberAttendanceID { get; set; }
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public string MemberNo { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ArrivalTime { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AttendanceItem> AttendanceItems { get; set; }
    public virtual @event @event { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model:**

```
public class AttendanceTrackingEntry
{        
    public Int32 EventID { get; set; }
    public String memberNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime ArrivalTime { get; set; }
    public List<AttendanceItems> AttendanceItems { get; set; }
}
```

MappingConfig.cs in App_Start:

```
Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<AttendanceTrackingEntry, AttendanceTracking>()                    
                .ForMember(dest => dest.EventID,
                           opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EventID))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.MemberNo,
                           opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.memberNo))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ArrivalTime,
                           opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ArrivalTime))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AttendanceItems,
                           opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AttendanceItems)); 
                .ForMember(dest => dest.@event,
                           opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(dest => dest.memberAttendanceID,
                          opt => opt.Ignore());                   
        });
        Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<AttendanceItems, AttendanceItem>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.EventItemsID,
                           opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EventItemsID))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.answer,
                           opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Answer))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.MemberAttendanceID,
                           opt => opt.Ignore())                    
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AttendanceTracking,
                          opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(dest => dest.eventItem,
                          opt => opt.Ignore());
        });
```

Lastly the call in the controller:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AttendanceTracking LogAttendance = new AttendanceTracking();
            //Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            LogAttendance = Mapper.Map<AttendanceTrackingEntry, AttendanceTracking> (attendanceTrackingEntry);                

            db.SaveChanges();
```

Note the controller code continues with proper syntax to complete the if I am just not showing it in this snip.

I read through [Automapper missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677889/automapper-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping) but it did not help.

I ended up trying adding Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

And got:

> The following property on eventTracking.Models.AttendanceItem cannot be mapped: 
>   AttendanceItems
>   Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type eventTracking.Models.AttendanceItem.
>   Context:
>   Mapping to property AttendanceItems from eventTracking.Models.ViewModels.AttendanceItems to eventTracking.Models.AttendanceItem
>   Mapping to property AttendanceItems from System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[eventTracking.Models.ViewModels.AttendanceItems, eventTracking, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] to System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[eventTracking.Models.AttendanceItem, eventTracking, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
>   Mapping from type eventTracking.Models.ViewModels.AttendanceTrackingEntry to eventTracking.Models.AttendanceTracking
>   Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException' was thrown.

So the problem seems to be writing the view model list of items to the data model list.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: You should also create map between `AttendanceItem` classes. And please provide full "Missing type map configuration" message.

Comment: OK, I have added attendanceItem Map so I'm updating my post above as I now have different error message. I'll post the whole error message as well.

Comment: I'm thinking the issue is in my AttendanceItems Map I've got the map set to ignore MemberAttendanceID which is the foreign key that needs to be passed from the AttendanceTrackng model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling Mapper.Initialize() twice. You should nest both mapping configurations under a single initialisation:

```
Mapper.Initialize(
            config =>
            {
                config.CreateMap<AttendanceTrackingEntry, AttendanceTracking>()
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.EventID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EventID))
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.MemberNo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.memberNo))
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.ArrivalTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ArrivalTime))
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.AttendanceItems, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AttendanceItems))
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.@event, opt => opt.Ignore())
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.memberAttendanceID, opt => opt.Ignore());

                config.CreateMap<AttendanceItems, AttendanceItem>()
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.EventItemsID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EventItemsID))
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.answer, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Answer))
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.MemberAttendanceID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MemberAttendanceID))
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.AttendanceTracking, opt => opt.Ignore())
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.eventItem, opt => opt.Ignore());
            });
```

Comment: Thanks that got rid of my error. It's my first time using AutoMapper so I totally missed that one.