# How do I use automapper in a repository?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, repository, automapper

In my repository I'd like to make use of a viewmodel because the data that I'm returning is quite heavy to serialize.  I am returning this data for my KendoUI Grid to use but the mapping is throwing errors back despite being correctly references.

I have a ViewModel called VesselsViewModel:

**ViewModel**

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{
    public class VesselsViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "ID")]
        public int vessel_idx { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string vessel_name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "IMONO")]
        public string imono { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Type")]
        public string vessel_type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I access the viewmodel in my controller like so (using Automapper):

**Index Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var vessels = _repository.GetAll();
        var vm = Mapper.Map<VesselsViewModel>(vessels);
        return View(vm);
    }
```

When I run my project however I get the following error:

**Error**

```
{"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nList`1 -> VesselsViewModel\r\nSystem.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyProject.Models.tbl_vessels, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> MyProject.ViewModels.VesselsViewModel\r\n\r\nDestination path:\r\nVesselsViewModel\r\n\r\nSource value:\r\nSystem.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyProject.Models.tbl_vessels]"}
```

I have the mapping specified in the Global.asax but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

**Mapping Global.asax**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<tbl_vessels, VesselsViewModel>().ReverseMap();
```

Here is my repository for reference:

**Repository.cs**

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private seabrokersEntities db;
    private DbSet<T> dbSet;

    public Repository()
    {
        db = new seabrokersEntities();
        dbSet = db.Set<T>();
    }

    //
    // GET : All
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return dbSet.ToList();
    }
}
```

**IRepository.cs**

```
 public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();        
        T GetById(object Id);
        void Insert(T obj);
        void Update(T obj);
        void Delete(Object Id);
        void Save();
    }
```

What have I done wrong that might have caused this issue or am I missing something? I know that automapper has changed the way it handles mapping so perhaps I need to alter what I'm doing but not sure how.

As a side note, if I manually map out the classes it works fine for example.

**Manual Mapping**

```
IEnumerable<VesselsViewModel> model = vessels.Select(
            x => new VesselsViewModel
            {
                vessel_idx = x.vessel_idx,
                vessel_name = x.vessel_name,
                vessel_type = x.vessel_type
            });
```

Many thanks

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677889/automapper-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping

Comment: what is `tbl_vessels`?

Comment: Hi Yanayaya, I have the same issue. Did you manage to find out how to do it?