# Missing Type Map Configuration Or Unsupported Mapping AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have this code:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id, string detailsDate)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var tblPersonnel = new tblPersonnel();

    using (var _context = new ScalehouseModel()) // for disposing
    {
        tblPersonnel = _context.tblPersonnels.Find(id);
    }


    if (tblPersonnel == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    Mapper.Initialize(config => config.CreateMap<tblPersonnel, PersonnelDetailsVm>());
    PersonnelDetailsVm person = Mapper.Map<tblPersonnel, PersonnelDetailsVm>(tblPersonnel);

.... // and more but the error happens on the line above.
```

}

After an ajax success, I am redirecting to the Details page, which the action you can see above.  I am getting run time errors like so:

[image]

I have researched [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677889/automapper-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping) and disposed my EF, but still not working and getting same error.

What do I need to do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In order for auto mapper to work, best way is to add automapper configuration in pipeline.
Here is how you can do

Step 1: Create a static class Mapping profile, and add all your mappings in this class

```
public static class MappingProfile
{
    public static MapperConfiguration InitializeAutoMapper()
    {
        MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<tblPersonnel, PersonnelDetailsVm>();
        });
        return config;
    } 
}
```

Step 2: Inorder to configure, register automapper configuration in Application_Start() method in Global.asax.cs

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        //Add AutoMapper configuration here.
        MappingProfile.InitializeAutoMapper();
    }
```

Give it a try.

Comment: `MapperConfiguration` is not an option for me.  Using version 4.1.1