# Problems while mapping using automapper C#

Tags: c#, automapper

Have to transfer data from old database to new with some changes in the field. Tried using AutoMapper for the same. Below is the code

```
var crudCommonV1 = new HAES.EDMS.DAL.CRUD.CRUDCommon<HAES.EDMS.DAL.Address>();
var addressV1List = crudCommonV1.GetAll();
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
    cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
    cfg.CreateMap<HAES.EDMS.DAL.Address, HAES.EDMS.V2.DAL.Address>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ForeignAddress, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.OverrideAddress));
});
//automapper
IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var addressListMappedFromV2ToV1 = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<HAES.EDMS.DAL.Address>, IEnumerable<HAES.EDMS.V2.DAL.Address>>(addressV1List);
```

But it throws an exception

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException
>
> HResult=0x80131500
>
> Message=Error mapping types.
>
> Source=
>
> StackTrace:

Inner Exception 1:

> AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Inner Exception 2:

> AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Any idea what am doing wrong here?

EDIT :

Models :
HAES.EDMS.DAL.V2.Address

```
public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
public System.Guid CollegeId { get; set; }
public short TypeId { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.Guid> PersonId { get; set; }
public string Pincode { get; set; }
public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
public string City { get; set; }
public string State { get; set; }
public string ForeignAddress { get; set; }
public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
public System.DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
```

HAES.EDMS.DAL.Address

```
public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
public short TypeId { get; set; }
public System.Guid PersonId { get; set; }
public string Pincode { get; set; }
public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
public string OverrideAddress { get; set; }
public string City { get; set; }
public string State { get; set; }
public string Remark { get; set; }
public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedOn { get; set; }
public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
```

Comment: Show us these models you're mapping.  We need a [mcve] to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automapper missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677889/automapper-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping)

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. Only after I leave out the `cfg.CreateMap<...>()` call, it fails with the same error you mentioned. Are you sure the problem is happening at **this** place and for **this** mapping?

Comment: Maybe try commenting one by one property and run app after, to brute force detect which one is causing crash?

Answer (score 1):

I think Peter is correct. AutoMapper needs a custom map because of the type mismatch on "UpdatedOn". Change your createmap line to something like this...

```
cfg.CreateMap<HAES.EDMS.DAL.Address, HAES.EDMS.V2.DAL.Address>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.ForeignAddress, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.OverrideAddress))
                    .ForMember(m => m.UpdatedOn, o => o.MapFrom(f => f.UpdatedOn ?? DateTime.Today));
```

You can change the default behavior but you cant really just use .value on the property in case it's null.

Comment: Well actually I just tried it, and that missing field mapping is **not** the cause of the failure (at least not with AutoMapper v9.0.0).

Comment: Agreed. You beat me to it but i cannot reproduce it. I thought maybe a type issue on .getall but I cant break it there either. Is there more of the program you can share? Type of project, anything about the .getall method. So far, this runs fine.

Comment: The exception is thrown by the last line of the code I shared. As for the project I simply created a console app where referred to the DLL of two different projects from where am getting the two models.