# Automapper missing type map configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong here, I have configured AutoMapper as follows

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MetingenView), typeof(Meting));
```

And in the controller like this:

```
public MetingenController(IMapper mapper)
{
    this._mapper = mapper;
}
```

After, I use it like this:

```
var entity = await this.Context.MetingenView.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(g =>g.IdMeting == key);
if (entity == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}
data.Patch(entity);
var meting = await this.Context.Meting.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IdMeting == key);
this._mapper.Map(entity, meting);
```

Then the error rolls out:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration
>   or unsupported mapping.

EDIT:

Here are the Meting, and MetingenView classes:

```
public partial class Meting
{
    public int IdMeting { get; set; }
    public int IdKoeling { get; set; }
    public int IdWerknemer { get; set; }
    public int IdGebouw { get; set; }
    public int Temperatuur { get; set; }
    public DateTime AfgenomenTijd { get; set; }
    public string ProductNaam { get; set; }
    public string Actie { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DatumOntstaan { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DatumMutatie { get; set; }
    public int IndVerwijderd { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DatumVerwijderd { get; set; }

    public virtual Gebouw IdGebouwNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Koeling IdKoelingNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Werknemer IdWerknemerNavigation { get; set; }
}



public partial class MetingenView
{
    [Key]
    public int IdKlant { get; set; }
    public string Locatie { get; set; }
    public string SoortKoeling { get; set; }
    public int IdMeting { get; set; }
    public int IdKoeling { get; set; }
    public int IdWerknemer { get; set; }
    public int IdGebouw { get; set; }
    public int Temperatuur { get; set; }
    public string Actie { get; set; }
    public string ProductNaam { get; set; }
    public DateTime AfgenomenTijd { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you configured the mapping? Can you add the source and destination classes to the question so that I can help you with configuring the mapping?

Comment: This error has the missing mapping in it, please read the error more carefully or debug to find the extended exception stack

Comment: Mapping types:
MetingenView -> Meting
HACCPWebAPI.Models.MetingenView -> HACCPWebAPI.Models.Meting
   at lambda_method(Closure , MetingenView , Meting , ResolutionContext )
   at HACCPWebAPI.Controllers.MetingenController.Patch(Int32 key, Delta`1 data) in \\lore\Stagiaires\Daan\Examples\InlogExampleService\InlogExampleService\Controllers\MetingenController.cs:line 61

Comment: At line 61, I called this._mapper.Map(entity, meting);
If thats what you mean?

Comment: Please add the `Meting` and `MetingView` classes to the question

Comment: I added them :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automapper missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677889/automapper-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping)

Comment: @SelimYıldız I did take a look at it before making this question, but couldn't figure it out, I'm still a starting programmer :/

Comment: There must be configuration like this `Mapper.CreateMap<MetingenView, Metingen>();`, do you have it? And `AutoMapperConfig.Configure();`as well..

Comment: I did try adding that, but I only got red lines, but to be clear where exactly would that have to be placed? in startup or in the controller?

Comment: In Application_Start() you need to configure `Mapper.CreateMap<MetingenView, Metingen>();`

Comment: AutoMapper configures using conventions by default. If you have properties that have the same name between two classes, it will map those. If you have properties that need to be mapped from non matching property names, or a destination property with no corresponding source property, you need to tell it where to get that value.

Comment: @DaanT It seems like youy do not get how automapper works quite yet. You need to be able to map one property directly to one other property by naming convention. If this is not the case, you need to declare them manually. As of now, I have no public repo to show you, but I will try to upload one shortly

Answer (score 1):

I think the mapping between `Meting` and `MetingenView` is not configured in AutoMapper. If you use Asp.Net Core, you could create a profile.

```cs
public class MetingProfile : Profile
{
    public MetingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<MetingenView, Meting>();
    }
}
```

This would create a default mapping that two types have the same property. If you want to config property mapping manually, Function `ForMember()` would be used.

For example, if you wish that the property `MetingenView.IdGebouw` maps `Meting.IndVerwijderd`, you can code this:

```cs
CreateMap<MetingenView, Meting>()
    .ForMember(dest=>dest.IdGebouw, opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src.IndVerwijderd));
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core