# C# mapping a controller model class to domain model class

Tags: c#, .net, list, api, automapper

I have a controller model classes as follows

```
 public class Request 
    {
        public Account Account { get; set; }
    }

public class Account
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public List<Holder> Holder { get; set; }
    }

public class Holder
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

I have domain classes as follows

```
public class AccountRequest
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public List<Holder> Holder { get; set; }
    }

public class Holder
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Now when i do mapping in the AccountMapper as

```
CreateMap<Models.Request, AccountRequest>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Holder, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Account.Holder));
```

I am getting an error
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Mapping types:
Holder -> Holder
Controllers.v2.Models.Holder -> Contracts.Domain.Holder

Can anyone help me on how to handle the model class or mapper, i used list because the request payload looks like, is there any other way to do this?

```
"Holder": [
{
"FirstName": "abc",
"LastName": "xyz"
},
{
"FirstName": "tqq",
"LastName": "kdi"
}
]
}
```

Comment: The error message is clear. You didn't have the mapping rule which maps Holder Controllers.v2.Models.Holder -> Contracts.Domain.Holder.

Comment: Why not using autumaper library https://code-maze.com/automapper-net-core/. Just imlement the profile class it wiill do the magic for you .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677889/automapper-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping-error and register the automapper dependency injection